# CSS target UL by LI class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to target a UL that has no class, I have no control over the HTML that is output...

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="item">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to apply an image bullet like this....

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
}
```

There are many different UL tags on the page so is there a way I can just target this one?

Comment: You could use the [CSS3 :nth-child() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Comment: @Paulie_D He has no control over the HTML, he wants to select `ul` which has no class, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

"*I am trying to target a UL that has no class*", you can use `:not()` selector.

```
ul:not([class]){
  ...
}
```

This will apply style if there is no `class attr` on `ul`

```css
ul:not([class]) {
  list-style:circle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 4</li>
</ul>

<ul class>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```